# What's the best way to keep abreast of Cassandra security releases?

Tags: security, cassandra

We use Apache Casssandra and want to be able to keep abreast of any security updates so that we can jump on them and update ASAP. I'm happy to go in search of feature and patch releases periodically, but I'd like security fixes to come and find me.

Is there a dedicated mailing list?

An RSS feed?

Comment: You could ask for a notification feature to be built into the product itself. I'm currently using Netdata and Traefik, and they both do this (Traefik uses its logs to do it, which might be best for Cassandra; Netdata and similar web apps use a toolbar/dashboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not very often, but they do come up on the dev mailing list. I don't know of anywhere else so it might be a lot to filter through. Your best bet is probably following events on Jira or creating a subscription on it to notify you. ie:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CASSANDRA%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20security